# How to search japanese name using a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode

I am writing a stored procedure for searching the Japanese name from the table which contains Japanese unicode strings. I have declared input parameter as `nvarchar`

But the application is sending me search string in `'search_string'` format NOT in `N'search string'` format. How do I perform searching?

Comment: Have a look at `COLLATE`

Comment: if the application is sending you data in the wrong format is not a sql issue but an application's one; you provide no detail about the application so no way to help... about the search, use a `SELECT` stetement.

Comment: what is the your DB Collation ?

Comment: The only real solution is to fix the application bug - they are sending ASCII when they should be sending UNICODE. By converting Japanese to ASCII before sending it to the stored procedure, the application may have *already* mangled the data. Modifying the stored procedure to hard-code a collation *could* be a dirty fix, but it could break other languages. The collation won't fix already mangled text though

Comment: suppose i am calling procedure with parameter 'japanese_string' instead of N'japanese string'.is there still any way to search the names.